# How do I fix my material texture rendering issue in Unity?

Tags: unity, textures, rendering

I am very new to Unity and was just testing out a few things to make my first ever game. I tried to make a material for my obstacle and I noticed that there is some texture issue. It shows pink lines and all other colors when at a close look. This can also be seen when the material color is brighter. How would I fix this?

My Unity version is Unity 2017.1.0f3.

[image: The bottom right is how the texture should look and the rest is the texture outcome. Even in the preview on the assets folder show this issue.]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here are some clues :

### GPU

Make sure your GPU can handle the version of DirectX Unity is using (example : Unity running with DX11 and GPU was only capable of DX10). `Build Settings PC, Mac & Linux Standalone -> Other Settings -> Rendering` : Disable `Automatic Graphics API` and reorder the list of Graphics APIs for Windows that appears so that DX11 is at the bottom.

[image: DirectX]

### Lightning

Go to the top menu: `Window -> Lighting -> Scene`. Uncheck `Auto` at the bottom of the panel and click on `Clear baked data` in the dropdown menu next to the `Build` button.

Also, in the `Lightning` panel, under the `Environment Lightning` section, set to `Uncompressed` the `Reflection Source -> Compression` field.

[image: Lightning]

### Shader

Try to download the [shaders assets of Unity](https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive) and use the downloaded Standard shader

### Reflections

Turn off the HDR in Cubemap capture settings for the reflection probe